# How do I extract the recognition strategy of a Selenium Web Element during run time?

Tags: java, selenium

The problem I have is that my Page Object class finds all of the objects on the screen and then sends it to a more generic method to do the actual data entry.  During this data entry process, some objects become stale and I get the "StaleElementException".

My plan is to catch that exception and attempt to re-find the element again.

Is there a way of extract the selection strategy from the runtime WebElement object other than doing a "object.toString()" and then parsing it?

Comment: You could extend the WebElement class and store something like your selector type and/or xpath in a variable.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but I was looking to something along the lines of "webelement.getRecognitionStrategy()", since if I do a "web element.toString()" I can see the strategy used.

Comment: You can create dynamic page objects that identify the elements required.  Do not ever store pre-found elements as you will run into this problem.  Rather, create properties that represent the name of the element you want and each time you want to do something, that property's getter method simply does this...   webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("SomeID"))...  By doing it this way you always have fresh copy of the element.

Comment: Thanks John.  You make a great point in not storing pre-found elements.  In my case I collect all elements first, put them in a TreeMap and then send them to a more generic fillScreen() method.  My issue was that a value in field 1 affected the type of field 5.  Meaning that when the screen was first displayed, field 5 was a drop down.  But because of a value in field 1, the page dynamically changed the type of the field.  So instead of being a drop down, it changed to a edit box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use page objects by defining the locators at the top of the class, then the constructor that verifies that we're on the right page (etc), and then methods for each action available on the page. Here's a simple example for the Google search page.

> GoogleSearchPage.java

```
public class GoogleSearchPage
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By waitForLocator = By.id("lst-ib"); // optional
    private By searchBoxLocator = By.id("lst-ib");
    private By searchButtonLocator = By.cssSelector("button[name='btnG']");
    private By feelingLuckyButtonLocator = By.id("gbqfbb");

    public GoogleSearchPage(WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        driver = webDriver;
        // wait for page to finish loading
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(waitForLocator));

        // see if we're on the right page
        if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://www.google.com"))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the Google search page. Current URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }
    }

    public void doSearch(String searchString)
    {
        driver.findElement(searchBoxLocator).sendKeys(searchString);
        driver.findElement(searchButtonLocator).click();
    }
}
```

> GoogleSearchTest.java

```
public class GoogleSearchTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        GoogleSearchPage googleSearchPage = new GoogleSearchPage(driver);
        googleSearchPage.doSearch("selenium");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("#q=selenium"));
    }
}
```

This is obviously a super simple example but it shows one good way to create page objects that should significantly reduce the frequency of StaleElementExceptions and, in some cases, speed up your script execution because you only scrape what you need and move on.

Reduce the urge to provide a `getX()` and `clickX()` method for each and every element on the page. Instead favor task based methods. Ask yourself what tasks a user is going to want to accomplish on the page and provide methods to do those tasks. It will keep your page object API much cleaner and more clear in what it provides to the consumer (you and other script writers).

Comment: That -- my friend -- is a really good idea.  I like your suggestion of
  driver.findElement(searchBoxLocator).sendKeys(searchString);<br>

This ensures that you are always getting a fresh copy of the element.  The situation that initiated this thread turns out to be a bug in the application.  

When the screen is first displayed, there is a drop down box that changes to an edit box due to a value in a previous field  But it illustrates very well the necessity of doing a search right before you are about to use the object.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: That is a great example.. there are pages that change (on purpose) after it's initially loaded. That's where the `// wait for page to finish loading` section comes into effect in the constructor. You can tailor that to whatever you need to to make sure the page is completely loaded. If you know that a particular element gets changed after the page loads, you can use that as your measure. In your case, maybe you wait for that particular edit box to appear to signal the page is done loading.